# Javascript switch not triggering

Tags: javascript, select, switch-statement

I have inconsistent behavior with a  dropdown and a switch statement. The select calls a routine that writes its index to a cookie which seems to work fine.

Change the index via the select and and the switch is ignored. I've tried it with string case values and numeric. The value for the select's index always prints correctly to the console. What am I missing?

```
 <label style="font-size:25px;" for="frq">Freq&nbsp;</label>
 <select style="font-size:25px;" width="20"  id="frq" onchange="changeFRQ()">
  <option value="600" selected>600</option> 
  <option value="650">650</option> 
  <option value="700">700</option>
  <option value="750">750</option>
  <option value="800">800</option>
  <option value="850">850</option>
</select>


function frequency(value) {

document.getElementById("frq").selectedIndex = frq;

console.log("frq:"+ frq);


switch(frq) {
  case "0":
    freq=600;
    console.log("600");
    break;
  case "1":
    freq=650;
    console.log("650");
    break;
  case "2":
    freq=700;
    console.log("700");
    break;
  case "3":
    freq=750;
    console.log("750");
    break;
  case "4":
    freq=800;
    console.log("800");
    break;
  case "5":
    freq=850;
    console.log("850");
    break;
  default:
    freq=600;
}

}
```

Comment: Please explain this line `document.getElementById("frq").selectedIndex = frq;` and why do you have different name for the function `frequency` and `changeFRQ`?

Comment: What does this line do? document.getElementById("frq").selectedIndex = frq;

Comment: The select statement onchange does not call the function frequency. The changeFRQ function called by onchange writes a cookie value. The function frequency depends on the index value of the select.

Comment: document.getElementById("frq").selectedIndex = frq; gives the chosen index of the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your switch statement you are checking string cases, so you have to convert toString() your selectedIndex, try this syntax:

```js
function changeFRQ(value) {
  let frq = document.getElementById("frq").selectedIndex.toString();

  switch(frq) {
    case "0":
      freq=600;
      console.log("600");
      break;
    case "1":
      freq=650;
      console.log("650");
      break;
    case "2":
      freq=700;
      console.log("700");
      break;
    case "3":
      freq=750;
      console.log("750");
      break;
    case "4":
      freq=800;
      console.log("800");
      break;
    case "5":
      freq=850;
      console.log("850");
      break;
    default:
    }
  
  console.log("frq:"+ freq);
}
```

```html
<label style="font-size:25px;" for="frq">Freq&nbsp;</label>
 <select style="font-size:25px;" width="20"  id="frq" onchange="changeFRQ()">
  <option value="600" selected>600</option> 
  <option value="650">650</option> 
  <option value="700">700</option>
  <option value="750">750</option>
  <option value="800">800</option>
  <option value="850">850</option>
</select>
```